# Making an HTML form Work

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make my first Contact form. I have already done the HTML & CSS part. Maybe there are some errors in the HTML tagging.

Now that my HTML/CSS looks fine I need to make it work so the submissions get sent to my email and the page displays a Thank you message or redirects to a thank u page.

Can someone help me with the code for creating a secure functionality for the form to make it work?

Also i would like to add a captcha to the form to avoid spam submissions.

Live link of form - http://wishamemory.com/makeawish/index.html

The HTML code of the form is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Quick Minimal Contact Form</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<form id="contact-form">
  <p>WISH A MEMORY!</p>
  <p>I
    <label for="your-wish">wish</label> for
    <input type="text" name="your-wish" id="wish" minlength="3" placeholder="(describe your wish here)" required></p>

  <p>  
    <label for="your-location">in</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-location" id="location" minlength="3" placeholder="(location in Goa only)" required>

    <label for="your-date">on</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-date" id="date" minlength="3" placeholder="(dates)" required></p>

  <p>***********</p>
  <p>
    <label for="your-credits">Is this wish for yourself or dedicated to someone else?</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-credits" id="credits" minlength="3" placeholder="Who is the lucky one?" required></p>
  <p>
    <label for="your-budget">Preferred budget to make this wish a reality:</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-budget" id="budget" minlength="3" placeholder="(amount in INR)" required></p>

  <p>
    <label for="your-maxbudget">Maximum you can spend to make the experience even more memorable:</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-maxbudget" id="maxbudget" minlength="3" placeholder="(let's make it special)" required></p>

  <p>
    <label for="your-reason">Why do you think this wish deserves becoming a memory?</label>
    <textarea name="your-reason" id="your-reason" placeholder="(Not all wishes come true. Share some background and the importance of this wish)" class="expanding" required></textarea>
    </p>

  <p>Personal details</p>
  <p>
    <label for="your-name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-name" id="name" minlength="3" placeholder="(full name)" required></p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="your-email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="phone">Mobile number</label>
    <input type="text" name="your-phone" id="phone" placeholder="(mobile number)" required>
  </p>

    <p>
    <button type="submit">
      <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
    l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
      </svg>
      <small>send</small>
    </button>
  </p>
</form>

<small class='website'>Powered by <a href='http://wishamemory.com/' target='_blank'>wishamemory.com</a></small>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried making a mail.php as follows to test. And in my HTML file changed

```
<form id="contact-form">
```

for this

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
```

mail.php file

```
<?php 
$your-wish = $_POST['your-wish'];
$your-location = $_POST['your-location'];
$your-date = $_POST['your-date'];
$formcontent="From: $your-name \n Message: $wish";
$recipient = "arminbaig@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $your-email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

but I get the following error on this url - http://wishamemory.com/makeawish/mail.php

This page isn’t working

wishamemory.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: You will need a PHP part to your form, what have you tried so far?

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help.

Comment: do you know that there are tons of similar answers here on SO and also tutorials googling for this topic? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: These are some easy and not so easy (also very generalized) questions that you should be first researching on your own. If you do the research and still have a specific problem/question, then you can ask on here.

Comment: Contact form is one of the the first basic exercises you do when learning PHP. There for, there are literally, and i mean literally, hundreds of thousands of examples. But... you disregard those and come straight here asking us to do it for you?

Comment: Take it easy guys.. I appreciate your concerns.. 
I have updated the post with details on my effort to fix it before posting here..

If you can only point me in the right direction i will be happy..
Thanks

Comment: I don't know where to point you because I do not know what the problem is. You only described what you want, not what specific question you have. If there are errors, tell us what they are.

Comment: @PhillipWeber thanks for the tip on the SMTP server.. I will look into this.

And the others, thanks for sparing your time in writing so much to try and educate me on how to learn! Instead of trying to help with the problem at hand..

Been my first post here on SO... I thought i will be able to move forward with my assignment by posting here but it definitely turned out to be a total waste of time. So thanks for making it even more difficult.. 

When you guys get your heads out of the code or whatever it is thats breaking it, my advice is work a bit on your attitude...

Comment: @ArminBaig For most coders, knowledge has come at a GREAT expense of time and effort. Keep that in mind!

Comment: @PhillipWeber I have a lot of respect for programmers. I have worked with many great ones. In the very first place when I seeked for help here means I know I have come to a place where there are better experts than me for the task. Gaining knowledge for everything (not just coding) comes after a lot of hardwork. Nothing comes easy. My goal is not to become a programmer. I just needed some guidance for a simple problem. Anyone who has wisdom and lots of knowledge doesn't need to boast about the hardwork they have put in. Its only the half wits who cry out loud!

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `action` atribute in `<form>` tag
like this `<form id="something" action="link-to-php file">`

you have to add mail.php in action attribute like this,

```
    <form action="mail.php" id="contactform" method="post">
-------
------------
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. I tried your suggestion.. but getting this error 

This page isn’t working

wishamemory.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Is your php server setup for email?

Comment: You need a valid SMTP server to handle the request, I believe you can use gmail but you need to connect using authentication... you may want to look into using a php email library... I use PEAR

Comment: make sure you have enabled error detection in php ini file

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    resize: vertical;
}

label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.col-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.col-75 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Form</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the effect. When the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other.</p>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="country">Country</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="australia">Australia</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-25">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-75">
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the relevance of your response. Whats this for?